# Command for checking the Version of Install in OpenStack AIO

Tags: openstack

How should i find out the open Stack Version installed in a ubuntu Setup, I have tried the open stack commands related to Open Stack --version , but it does not show the correct picture

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, you can have a mix of versions. This is even supported in certain situations, for example when you upgrade a cloud. A cloud might even consist of services of several versions, though that is probably not supported.

In your case, being an all-in-one installation, `nova-manage --version` is an adequate solution. The major version number corresponds to the position of the version name's initial in the alphabet, e.g. 20 would mean T, therefore Train.